# Accessing a DOM node

Tags: javascript, dom

Using just the DOM API, what are all of the different ways I can access a node?

For example, I know I can call `document.getElementById("header");`. I'd like a complete list of ways to get access to this node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"access" can come in two forms.  Properties and Methods.

In this list m is a node object (HTML element).
Some properties:

- m.innerHTML - the text
- m.nodeName -the name
- m.nodeValue - the value
- m.parentNode - the parent node
- m.childNodes - the child nodes
- m.attributes - the attributes nodes

Some methods:

- m.getElementById(id) - the element with id
- m.getElementsByTagName(name) - get all elements by tag name
- m.appendChild(node) - insert child node to m
- m.removeChild(node) - remove child node from m

Some "special" ones:

- document.documentElement - root node of document
- document.body - direct access to body element tag

Note: there are other proporties such as .length etc for specific use when applicable.

EDIT: A reference to the specification can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html

EDIT2: A reference to the level 1 HTML specification here: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html

EDIT3: Complete ECMA script binding: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/ecma-script-language-binding.html

Comment: Note not all implimentations support all methods or properties.

Answer (score 2):

The following list contains collections, properties and methods that can be used to access a node. Some of them are element specific, some of them are members of each element, some of them are only available through the document object.

Collections: 
all, anchors, applets, areas, cells, childNodes, children, elements, embeds, forms, frames, images, links, options, rows, scripts, tBodies

Properties:
body, caption, document, documentElement, firstChild, firstElementChild, frameElement, lastChild, lastElementSibling, nextElementSibling, nextSibling, offsetParent, ownerDocument, parentElement, parentNode, previousElementSibling, previousSibling, tFoot, tHead

Methods:
getElementById, getElementsByClassName, getElementsByName, getElementsByTagName, getElementsByTagNameNS

You can find further details and examples here:
[Element handling objects, properties and methods in JavaScript](http://help.dottoro.com/ljpmordd.php)